# Function to capture change between values in different columns

Tags: python, pandas

Can someone please help me with a simple function to capture the change between open and Last as per the examples below:

The data:

```
             Open   High    Low    Last 
Timestamp                                       
2014-03-04  1783.50 1796.00 1783.50 1793.25
2014-03-05  1793.25 1796.50 1790.50 1794.00 
2014-03-06  1798.00 1802.25 1795.00 1797.75 
2014-03-07  1804.75 1805.50 1790.50 1798.75
```

Its easy enough for me to do a similar function when capturing something like the range between `High` and `Low` with:

```
def daily_range(df):
    return df['High'] - df['Low']
```

But how do we do a similar function the with `Open` and `Last`?

I will use `apply` on this function to get a new column in my dataframe and desired output is shown below:

```
           Open   High     Low     Last     Desired output
Timestamp                                       
2014-03-04  1783.50 1796.00 1783.50 1793.25   9.75
2014-03-05  1793.25 1796.50 1790.50 1794.00   0.75
2014-03-06  1798.00 1802.25 1795.00 1797.75  -0.25
```

Basically if `Open` is higher than `Last` I need to do `Open` - `Last` and if `Last` is higher than `Open` I need to do `Last` - `Open`.  I could do this with an `if` in the function but there must be a better way to do this simple task and I would like to find this.

Update:

Sorry if my question was not correctly worded.  I did however show desired output with negative values desired output (see above).

On 2014-03-06 below the move was -0.25 but the code given in the answer shows 0.25 not -0.25.  Can you help with this?

```
             Open   Last    desired
Timestamp           
2014-03-04  1783.50 1793.25 9.75
2014-03-05  1793.25 1794.00 0.75
2014-03-06  1798.00 1797.75 0.25
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
df['desired'] = (df['Open'] - df['Last']).abs()
```

This gives you the absolute value of the difference (if `df['Last']` is greater than `df['Open']`, it becomes `df['Last'] - df['Open']`)

Your sample output is, on the other hand, is the result of `df['Last'] - df['Open']`, without the absolute value.

Comment: Thanks for this.  When I try to apply `d1['OC_Range'] = d1.apply(open_close_range,axis=1)` I get `AttributeError: ("'float' object has no attribute 'abs'", 'occurred at index 2014-03-04 00:00:00')`

Comment: Why are you using apply? What is `open_close_range`?

Comment: Ignore my last comment  please.  However abs does not give me the negative values.

Comment: "Basically if Open is higher than Last I need to do Open - Last and if Last is higher than Open I need to do Last - Open." Based on this definition you shouldn't have negative values?

Comment: Please see updated post edit.  My desired output did show I wanted a negative value but sorry if I didn't explain properly.  I have tried to clarify.  I need this value to show whether the market went up or down which is why i need a negative value if `Last` is lower than `Open`

Comment: Your output seems like the result of `df[Last'] - df['Open']`.

Comment: You are correct an this answers my question.  Appreciate your help.  If you change your answer to this I will mark as accepted.